# Pandas copying specific cell values in column when conditions are met

Tags: python, pandas, function, for-loop, multiple-columns

I want to copy a cell value in a column B when column A meets specific condition as following and creating a new column C:

1. Whenever "Forward" switches to either "Stop" or "Backward"
2. Whenever "Backward" switches to either "Stop" or "Forward"

For example,

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Stop | 0 | 0 |
| Forward | 10 | 0 |
| Forward | 20 | 0 |
| Forward | 30 | 30 |
| Backward | 10 | 0 |
| Backward | 25 | 0 |
| Backward | 40 | 40 |
| Stop | 0 | 0 |
| Stop | 0 | 0 |
| Backward | 5 | 0 |
| Backward | 10 | 10 |
| Forward | 20 | 0 |
| Forward | 30 | 30 |
| Stop | 0 | 0 |

I tried to following code but it does not work, column C storing nothing.

```
   for idx, row in df.iterrows():
            if idx <= 1:
                continue

            A1 = row['A']
            A0 = df.iloc[idx + 1]['A']
            B1 = row['B']

            def C(df):
                if A1 == "Forward" and A0 == "Stop":
                    return B1
                if A1 == "Backward" and A0 == "Stop":
                    return B1
                elif A1 == "Forward" and A0 == "Backward":
                    return B1
                elif A1 == "Backward" and A0 == "Forward":
                    return B1

        df['C'] = df.apply(C, axis = 1)
```

I tried this too but it does not work

```
   for idx, row in df.iterrows():
            if idx <= 1:
                continue

            A1 = df.iloc[idx - 1]['A']
            A0 = row['A']
            B1 = df.iloc[idx - 1]['B']

            def C(df):
                if A1 == "Forward" and A0 == "Stop":
                    return B1
                if A1 == "Backward" and A0 == "Stop":
                    return B1
                elif A1 == "Forward" and A0 == "Backward":
                    return B1
                elif A1 == "Backward" and A0 == "Forward":
                    return B1

        df['C'] = df.apply(C, axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use boolean masks:

```
# is the value a Forward/Backward?
m1 = df['A'].isin(['Forward', 'Backward'])

# Is there a change of Forward/Backward?
s  = df['A'].where(m1)
m2 = s.ne(s.shift(-1))

# if both condition above are met assign 0
df['C'] = df['B'].where(m1&m2, 0)
```

Alternative:

```
# is the value a Forward/Backward?
m1 = df['A'].isin(['Forward', 'Backward'])

# Is there not a change of Forward/Backward?
s  = df['A'].where(m1)
m2 = s.eq(s.shift(-1))

# if both condition above are different (XOR), assign 0
df['C'] = df['B'].where(m1!=m2, 0)
```

Output:

```
           A   B   C
0       Stop   0   0
1    Forward  10   0
2    Forward  20   0
3    Forward  30  30
4   Backward  10   0
5   Backward  25   0
6   Backward  40  40
7       Stop   0   0
8       Stop   0   0
9   Backward   5   0
10  Backward  10  10
11   Forward  20   0
12   Forward  30  30
13      Stop   0   0
```

Intermediates:

```
# approach 1
           A   B   C     m1     m2  m1&m2
0       Stop   0   0  False   True  False
1    Forward  10  10   True  False  False
2    Forward  20  20   True  False  False
3    Forward  30   0   True   True   True
4   Backward  10  10   True  False  False
5   Backward  25  25   True  False  False
6   Backward  40   0   True   True   True
7       Stop   0   0  False   True  False
8       Stop   0   0  False   True  False
9   Backward   5   5   True  False  False
10  Backward  10   0   True   True   True
11   Forward  20  20   True  False  False
12   Forward  30   0   True   True   True
13      Stop   0   0  False   True  False

# approach 2
           A   B   C     m1     m2  m1!=m2
0       Stop   0   0  False  False   False
1    Forward  10   0   True   True   False
2    Forward  20   0   True   True   False
3    Forward  30  30   True  False    True
4   Backward  10   0   True   True   False
5   Backward  25   0   True   True   False
6   Backward  40  40   True  False    True
7       Stop   0   0  False  False   False
8       Stop   0   0  False  False   False
9   Backward   5   0   True   True   False
10  Backward  10  10   True  False    True
11   Forward  20   0   True   True   False
12   Forward  30  30   True  False    True
13      Stop   0   0  False  False   False
```

Comment: Brilliant! This code is much simpler and works perfectly.